# Checkbox list Style

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

My listbox is appearing differently in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

How can I make them look alike. I want 1px border
[image]

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbStatus" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Approved" Value="A"></asp:ListItem>

                        <asp:ListItem Text="Declined" Value="D"></asp:ListItem>

                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: Please post relevant markup code (ASPX and how it is rendered as HTML)

Comment: I edited the first post. please check

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox is one of those elements that will always render differently by different browsers. If you want the look to be unified I suggest one of jQuery plugins that turns ordinary checkboxes into styled controls.

For example your checkboxlist renders this HTML to browser:

```
<table id="cbStatus" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="cbStatus_0" type="checkbox" name="cbStatus$0" /><label for="cbStatus_0">Approved</label></td>
        <td><input id="cbStatus_1" type="checkbox" name="cbStatus$1" /><label for="cbStatus_1">Approved w/ Requirements</label></td>
        <td><input id="cbStatus_2" type="checkbox" name="cbStatus$2" /><label for="cbStatus_2">Declined</label></td><td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Using [PrettyCheckable](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/) plugin you can issue a single command to style it::

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prettyCheckable();
```

And here is what it looks like after: http://jsfiddle.net/WuFg9/

You can adjust the styles to whatever you want, borders, colors etc. etc.

Comment: Hello,I don't want to use external plugins. Those are not allowed here

Comment: Then you will have to implement something similar on your own.